# How to use MediaRecorder to capture video on Android?

Tags: android, user-permissions, mediarecorder

I would like to create a short video clip using the `MediaRecorder`, but I don't know how to use it.

In my manifest file I added these permissions before the application-end-tag:

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_VIDEO" />
</application>
```

And I create a `MediaRecorder` with this code when the user press a button:

```
    private void startRecording() {
    mRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
    mRecorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.CAMERA);
    mRecorder.setVideoEncoder(MediaRecorder.VideoEncoder.H264);
    mRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);
    mRecorder.setOutputFile("myvideo.mpeg4");

    try {
        mRecorder.prepare();
    } catch (IOException e) {

    }
    mRecorder.start();
}
```

But when I run that code I get a "Force close - The application has stopped unexpectedly. Please try again" message. How should I use `MediaRecorder` and how can I debug my application to see what causes the exception? Do I need to add any other user permissions to my manifest file?

Comment: Can you post the logcat for more details

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First declare the permissions in your Manifest file...

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_VIDEO" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.Camera"/>
```

Then in your main app code...

```
Camera cam = Camera.open();
cam.unlock();

if(recorder == null) { recorder=new MediaRecorder(); }

recorder.setCamera(camera);
recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.CAMCORDER);
recorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.CAMERA);
recorder.setProfile(CamcorderProfile.get(CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_HIGH));
recorder.setOutputFile(fileName);
recorder.setPreviewDisplay(holder.getSurface());

try{ recorder.prepare(); recorder.start(); } 
catch( IOException e ) { e.printStackTrace(); }
```

Answer (score 0):

> To advertise that your application depends on having a camera, put a  tag in the manifest file:

```
<manifest ... >
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera"
              android:required="true" />
...
```

> Record a Video with a Camera App

```
    static final int REQUEST_VIDEO_CAPTURE = 1;

 private void dispatchTakeVideoIntent() {
        Intent takeVideoIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE);
        if (takeVideoIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
            startActivityForResult(takeVideoIntent, REQUEST_VIDEO_CAPTURE);
        }
    }
```

// View the Video

```
 @Override
       protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,Intent intent) {
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_VIDEO_CAPTURE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) 
    {
        Uri videoUri = intent.getData();
        mVideoView.setVideoURI(videoUri);
    }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question you don't use MediaRecorder