# Use MediaRecorder API instead of Intent for camera recording in Android

Tags: java, android, mediarecorder, video-recording, android-video-record

I'm using the following code to record the camera in Android that uses the basic `Intent`. How can I change it to use `MediaRecorder` API instead of this Intent-based approach?

```
private Uri fileUri;
//...
        private void recordVideo() {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE);
            fileUri = getOutputMediaFileUri(MEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO);
            // set video quality
            intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, fileUri); // set the image file
    
            // start the video capture Intent
            startActivityForResult(intent, CAMERA_CAPTURE_VIDEO_REQUEST_CODE);
        }
    
    // ...
    
    @Override
        protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == CAMERA_CAPTURE_IMAGE_REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                // play the video given the global fileUri 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't use the Android SDK (my Java skills are on Windows only), but from a quick research...

See if [this tutorial](https://www.javatpoint.com/android-mediarecorder-example) helps you (more info further beow)... 
Just replace their audio setup (3GP) with the H264 & AAC setup from the [other Question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46720945/2057709).
Also read the section about *"Recording Video"* on [this article](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/107270/Recording-and-Playing-Video-on-Android) to understand the needed parts.

Also [declare permissions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7037755/how-to-use-mediarecorder-to-capture-video-on-android/28669937#28669937) in your Manifest.xml. An example of such manifest and related code is [here on Github](https://gist.github.com/scottgwald/7743453) (that one allows `RECORD_AUDIO` but you need also a `RECORD_VIDEO` so set as):

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_VIDEO"/>
```

Back to the tutorial, I cannot test their code but something like the below edit should get you started:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity 
{  
    MediaRecorder recorder;  
    File outputfile = null;  
    static final String TAG = "MediaRecording";
```

Then inside that class you add useful functions (initialise Recorder, start rec, stop rec, save file)...

```
public void initRecording(View view) throws IOException 
{  
    //Creating file  
    File dir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();  
    try { outputfile = File.createTempFile("video_test_android", ".mp4", dir); } 
    catch (IOException e) 
    {  
      Log.e(TAG, "external storage access error");  
      return;  
    }  
    
     //# Create a new instance of MediaRecorder
    recorder = new MediaRecorder(); //create MediaRecorder object
    recorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.CAMERA);
    recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.CAMCORDER);
    recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);

    //# Video settings
    recorder.setVideoEncoder(MediaRecorder.VideoEncoder.H264); //contained inside MP4
    recorder.setVideoSize(640, 480); //width 640, height 480
    recorder.setVideoFrameRate(30);  //30 FPS
    recorder.setVideoEncodingBitRate(3000000); //adjust this for picture quality

    //# Audio settings
    recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AAC); //must always be AAC
    recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.getAudioSourceMax());
    recorder.setAudioEncodingBitRate(16);
    recorder.setAudioSamplingRate(44100);

    recorder.setOutputFile(outputfile.getAbsolutePath());  
    recorder.prepare();  
    
} 

public void startRecording(View view)
{
    recorder.start();
} 

public void stopRecording(View view)
{
    recorder.stop(); recorder.release(); 

    //# After stopping the recorder...
    //# Create the video file and add it to the Media Library.  
    addRecordingToMediaLibrary();
 
}

protected void addRecordingToMediaLibrary() 
{
    //# used to store a set of values that the ContentResolver can process
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues(4); //# 4 items (title, date, etc)

    long current = System.currentTimeMillis(); //# get recording time (date)

    //# size of 4 for values, all in String
    values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE, "Android Tina J - " + outputfile.getName());
    values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATE_ADDED, (int) (current / 1000));
    values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.MIME_TYPE, "video/mp4"); //# set MIME type
    values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA, outputfile.getAbsolutePath()); // data stream for the file

    //# provides applications access to the content model
    ContentResolver contentResolver = getContentResolver();

    //# The content:// style URI for the "primary" external storage volume.
    Uri base = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
    Uri newUri = contentResolver.insert(base, values);

    //# Request the media scanner to scan a file and add it to the media database
    sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE, newUri));

    //# if you need a notification...
    //Toast.makeText(this, "Created Media File : " + newUri, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

So to begin a recording, just inititalise the media recorder and do a `recorder.start();` to begin recording (camera and mic are used automatically according to your MediaRecorder settings).

Comment: Thanks. I did most of these steps...but still have problems running it.